# Layering software in presence of increasing number of typeclasses

Tags: scala, typeclass

A piece of software initially designed with 3 typeclasses has grown to use a large number of typeclasses. Let's take this example:

- You have a `Service[A,B]`
- You have a `TypeClass1[A]`
- You have a `TypeClass2[B]`
- You have a `TypeClass3[A,B,C]`
- You have a `TypeClass4[A]`
- You have a `TypeClass5[B]`
- You have a `TypeClass6[C]`
- You have a `TypeClass7[C]`
- You have a `TypeClass8[B]`

We have 6 known combinations of A,B,C which are fully disjoint (i.e. each combination contains types of A,B,C that are used only in that combination) . So now we have two options:

1. write a top-level method which would take 8 different typeclasses
2. create intermediate typeclasses that we could derive such as
   `TypeClass14[A]`, `Typeclass67[C]` and so on, so eventually you
   could end up having a `UberTypeClass[A,B,C]` which provides all the
   desired behaviour.

The second solution seems obviously more reasonable as a general programming approach: introducing intermediate layers and abstractions improves code quality in many ways. The challenge we face is the following:

1. If we do not summon the lower-level typeclasses at the intermediate layers by providing implicit conversions that stack them up, in reality we are just improving the syntax (but anyways, these are implicits!) but we didn't address the problem that the code lacked layering
2. If  we do summon the lower-level typeclasses, we do end up writing a lot of intermediate boilerplate (`TypeClass1Instances`, `TypeClass2Instances`, `Typeclass3Instances`)

What are the best practices when using typeclasses with relation to software layering?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following to bundle typeclasses up.

You can also generalize this code using shapeless's HLists to an arbitrary arity.

```
trait Lemma2[F1[_], F2[_], A] {
  val F1: F1[A]
  val F2: F2[A]
}

object Lemma2 {
  implicit def lemma[A, F1[_], F2[_]](implicit FA: F1[A], FB: F2[A]): 
    Lemma2[F1, F2, A] =
     new Lemma2[F1, F2, A] {
       val F1 = FA
       val F2 = FB
   }

}

trait LemmaSyntax {
  implicit def f1[F1[_], F2[_], A](implicit lemma: Lemma2[F1, F2, A]): F1[A] = {
    lemma.F1
  }

  implicit def f2[F1[_], F2[_], A](implicit lemma: Lemma2[F1, F2, A]): F2[A] = {
    lemma.F2
  }
}

import cats._
import cats.implicits._

object Test extends LemmaSyntax {
  type Proof[A] = Lemma2[Show, Eq, A]


   def foo[A : Proof](a: A): String = {
     a.show
   }
}

object Other {
  Test.foo("moo")
}
```

Comment: This goes in the direction of exposing all the types to the top layer without building intermediate abstractions. Doesn't this violate somehow modularity?

Comment: It depends on how you're thinking of it. Let's consider that I have a function which requires `TC1[_]` and `TC2[_]`. In the case that there are no laws which this composite typeclass obeys, I really just want to say to the type system, this function requires these two typeclasses which obey the respective laws of the typeclasses themselves. This often happens in application code. In the other case when there is a law to be followed, the mere existence isn't enough, so I'd introduce another `TC`.

Comment: A good example of the latter is a `Encoder[A]` and a `Decoder[A]`. Put them together you get a `Codec[A]` which needs to follow the law `a.encode.decode === a`. On the other hand I can't really state anything new between the `Show` and `Eq` in the example.